# Try-Catch positive numbers in java

Tags: java, numbers, try-catch

im trying this code but it didn't work, the code should ask you for number again and agin until you enter a positive number. Sorry for my bad english, tnx !

```
System.out.print("Precio: ");
precio[contPre] = Double.parseDouble(teclado.readLine());

try {
    double precioCatch = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(precio[contPre]));
    if (precioCatch < 0) 
        throw new Exception();
}catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Number must be >0");
    continue;
}
```

Comment: In order to do something again and again, you need to use some kind of loop (for, while). You have no loop in your code, so it will be executed only once.

Comment: Hi, Yes, you're right, I've already corrected it using if and while Tnx u soo much :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers guys, i found the solution and it works:

```
precio[contPre] = Double.parseDouble(teclado.readLine());
if (0 > precio[contPre]) {
    while (0 > precio[contPre]) {
        System.out.print("Number must be a positive: ");
        precio[contPre] = Double.parseDouble(teclado.readLine());
    }
}
```